# Check if AWS Lambda function is already running before run schedule cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda

I have a recurring AWS Lambda function, which is scheduled to run every 15 minutes. I would like to validate if it is running before being invoked again after 15 minutes.

Is there any AWS feature that checks this? Or will I have to develop another lambda to validate?

Comment: Set concurrency to 1; if you try to invoke while its still running you’ll get an error.

Comment: Set concurrency to 1 works for me, thanks!

Comment: Great! I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the AWS Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/per-function-concurrency.html), you an set the concurrency to either guarantee the that your function can reach a certain concurrency level, or, conversely, you can use concurrency to limit the maximum number of concurrent invocations.

To achieve your goal, simply set the concurrency to 1 and if there is another execution in progress your invocation will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum execution time of Lambda function is 15 minutes (note that this is not the default value which is 3 seconds). If you are running the lambda function on schedule, every 15 minutes then the previous one has either already finished or timed out, so the answer is no, the previous instance of the lambda function is not running.

Comment: my function is recursive, it's activated every 15 minutes but runs again after finished, so I have to check if it's running

Comment: I would not recommend using recursive Lambda functions. AWS wouldn't recommend it as well. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html

Comment: @SergioRBJ What do you mean by "my function is recursive"? Is it merely chaining or does it wait for a recursive call to finish, then continue running?